# Learning about a population mean

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test, mean

[image]

1. Assuming $H_0$ is true, what is the distribution of the test statistic?
   t(29)
2. Assuming $H_0$ is true, what is the expected value of the test statistic? 87.70
3. The sample mean of 87.7 was ___ standard errors below the mean of 90. 1.615

Can someone verify that my work is correct?  In particular, I'm not entirely sure about the second question.  Will the test statistic actually be 0 in this case (as it wouldn't deviate from the mean)?

Comment: For #2, it will be enlightening to state explicitly what $H_0$ asserts and then sit back and re-read the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Assuming H0 is true, what is the distribution of the test statistic? t(29)

No doubt this is the answer that was desired. However, it's strictly speaking incorrect -- without additional assumptions, the only possibly answer is "We can't tell".

> Assuming H0 is true, what is the expected value of the test statistic? 87.70

This is not correct. You have given the sample mean of the random variable.

You are being asked for the population mean of a t(29) distribution; your later surmise at the end is thinking more along the right kind of lines, but you display some confusion here that should lead you to ask about the difference, or at least to ask about *something*.

> The sample mean of 87.7 was _ standard errors below the mean of 90. 1.615

The question could be slightly clearer but I believe you have it right.

Comment: For the second question, should the answer actually be 90, then?  As then there is no deviation from the mean being tested in the hyptheses?

Comment: No. What is the thing you're being asked for the mean of?

Comment: The hypotheses are H0: u = 90 vs Ha: u < 90

Comment: Thanks, that should go in your question, but I didn't ask for the hypothesis. What is the object that question two asks you to *give the mean of*? You seem to be just randomly grabbing quantities out of the question in the hopes that you have the right answer. You need to stop and actually think about what it is saying.

Comment: So it's saying that if we assume the mean is actually 90, what is the value of the test statistic.  I see that t = -1.615 in the chart, but I don't believe this is the statistic I'm supposed to be looking for.

Comment: The table contains only sample information. You're being asked for a population quantity. What is the test statistic being used here? (this is *REALLY* simple. Maybe you should re-read your notes or text)

Comment: So can you explain why it would not be 0 in this case? If the nul hyphothesis is true, then how can we expect the test to produce anything other than 0?

Comment: The mean outcome when I roll a fair six-sided die is 3.5. I just rolled one and got a 2. How can that happen if my die is not biased? Likewise, if H0 is true, the test statistic doesn't take its population mean because sample values are not equal to population means. (If H0 is false, it doesn't take the population mean under H0 for other reasons as well.)

Comment: Is it just 29 then?

Comment: You're just randomly picking numbers out of the question again. There is no number anywhere in the question that will help you. STOP doing that. Again, **what is the test statistic being used here**? (The answer to that question ISN'T a number!) Please reread all comments made by me and whuber and just *think about what you're doing*. Maybe you can come up with a question to ask.

Comment: Isn't the test statistic the one sample t?

Comment: Also, if we're assuming H0 is true, wouldn't the desired value be exactly the center of a t(29) distribution (which is exactly at 0)?

Comment: Correct both times.

Comment: The advantage to you of me not just telling you the answer is that you get to discover you already had all the information (probably in your head). You actually know more than you realize. So not only are you now right, but you discover you already understood something that maybe it didn't seem like you did. You seem to be doing okay.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  I greatly appreciate it!